Program compiled with homebrew's clang don't have pretty printing support in lldb
For some reason, I want to use the latest Clang compiler, so I installed it from Homebrew.
I have installed the CodeLLDB extension in VS Code, and I have the following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> map = {
        {"k1", {"some", "thing", "str", "blababllblbla"}},
        {"k2", {"some", "thing", "str", "blababllblbla"}},
        {"k3", {"some", "thing", "str", "blababllblbla"}},
    };

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map2 = {
        {"k1", "2blababllblbla"},
        {"k2", "34blababllblbla"},
        {"k3", "b43lababllblbla"},
    };
    
    map["fkdsljfkld"] = {"dskfjdlfk","kljf df", "kjfsdklfjdsf"};
    
    std::cout << map["k1"][2];
    
    return 0;
}

When I compile this code with Homebrew's Clang using CMake like this:
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++" )
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang" )

and break at the end of the program, it does not pretty print the map and map2 variables; it shows <error: invalid value object> as element values.
If I compile it with Apple's Clang, it properly pretty prints the maps.
I tried changing the program's linked libc++ to homebrew's libc++ like this
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++/libc++.1.dylib playground

but that didn't worked :(
